# Best way to show a small view/dialog over an existing screen?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

All my views/pages in apps so far have been full screen UIViewControllers that i push and pop from the stack.

I see some apps create a new view/window that appears about the 1/3 the size of the full screen on an iPad, containing tables of items to select or other UI elements. They are commonly used to allow users to filter the current view they were on.

Seeing them in apps, I guess that they are just adding a UIView to there current screen and change its frame depending on where on the screen they want it to appear.

Or am I wrong? Is there another/better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little unclear from your question what the view looks like.

If the view is "attached" to a UI element (has a little triangular arrow connecting it to, e.g., a button) and goes away if you tap outside it, then it's a view presented from a [UIPopoverController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html).

If the view overlays everything and dims the content behind it, is likely a model view controller presented with a [presentation style](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIModalPresentationStyle) of ether page sheet or form sheet.

Both are common and easy to set up.  See the class documentation I have linked.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are talking about [UIPopovercontroller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html). There are several tutorials to build the same.[check this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1056/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-uipopovercontroller-tutorial). Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, these are probably normal modal view controllers whose `modalPresentationStyle` property is set to either `UIModalPresentationPageSheet` or `UIModalPresentationFormSheet`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can make your own UIViews and just add them as subviews. Another option for iPads specifically is with the UIPopoverController class.